# How do I change the “site” name in django-registration template email?

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-registration

I have email template:
Activate: {{ site }}/accounts/activate/{{ activation_key }}/

I want to set {{site}} to localhost. How can I do this without django-admin panel.
I want to use CONSTANT for this.

Comment: can you post the view that handle that template?

Answer (score 0):

From the django docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sites/

```
from django.contrib.sites.shortcuts import get_current_site

def my_view(request):
    current_site = get_current_site(request)
    if current_site.domain == 'foo.com':
        # Do something
        pass
    else:
        # Do something else.
        pass
```

The site information can be passed to your template